# Webpack 4 + Babel - Dynamic imports not working after adding the plugin

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-loader, dynamic-import

I'm using this ->

`"webpack": "^4.29.3",
"@babel/core": "^7.2.2",`

This is my `.babelrc` file ->

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "corejs": 2,
        "helpers": true,
        "regenerator": true,
        "useESModules": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

As you can see the plugin `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` is installed, but if i try to use it as `const Panel = React.lazy(() => import('../panel/panel'));`

It throws an error that a loader might be needed for this filetype (the file is .jsx, but i dont think it matters).

I also made a gist of my webpack config in case it matters -> https://gist.github.com/Taerarenai/c494e37c5cf3ba743acad2cd0e96c35f

Any tips ?

Comment: If you are using, @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs and @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import with webpack, you don't need to. webpack will bundle files with it's own module loading system that covers commonjs, dynamic import, es import, and amd. Adding them will only conflict with webpack.
See https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/
It's probably easier to see if you take a small demo where you use dynamic import and let it get bundled by webpack.